# Merging two XMLs with retaining attribute-value from base-xml

Tags: shell, merge

I have two XMLs which look like below. How to merge 2 of them with scripting to take values from new.xml & retainging non-existing attribute-value form base.xml

`base.xml`:

```
 <element name="ind"
          dbs="name1, name2, name4"
          server="ServerName"
          good-attribute="234"/>
```

My *new.xml* looks like this:

```
<element name="ind"
         description="My desc"
         dbId="someId"
         moreAttr="someVal"
         dbs="name1, name2, name4, name12, name3"
         server="ServerName" />
```

I would like to take latest `dbs` value from `new.xml` to `merge.xml` and with retaining `good-attribute` value present only in `base.xml`:

`merge.xml`:

```
<element name="ind"
         description="My desc"
         dbId="someId"
         moreAttr="someVal"
         dbs="name1, name2, name4, name12, name3"
         server="ServerName"
         good-attribute="234" />
```

With paste just `paste` fieldwise and `vimdiff` shows diff, but does not allow to select. Any inbuild support is there or need it to be implemented with replacements with sed + awk?

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a shell script. Or you might but it will be ridiculously complicated. You'll need a full scripting language and an XML parser. I am voting to migrate this to [so].

Comment: what is the structure of the xml documents? Are there other elements in addition to `<element/>`? How do you match elements from base.xml and new.xml? By their order? (i.e. the 1st element from base.xml corresponds to the 1st element from new.xml, etc)

Comment: Yes, there are more elements along with <element/> type. Mapping should happen based on element name, like 'ind' here in above eg.

Comment: is there a root element or just a sequence of `<element/>` e.g., one element per line? Are the names unique in each file?

Comment: Yes, there is a root element in the XML. And name of each element is unique in full XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a direct implementation in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python 2.5+ compatible
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def main():
    output_file = getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout)
    dict2xml(merge_dicts(*map(xml2dict, sys.argv[1:])), output_file)

def xml2dict(source):
    return dict((el.get('name'), el.attrib)
                for el in etree.parse(source).getiterator('element'))

def merge_dicts(base, new):
    merged = {}
    # for each element from new xml
    for name, attr in new.items():
        # combine attributes from base and new xmls preferring new values
        d = merged[name] = base.get(name, {})
        d.update(attr)
    return merged

def dict2xml(d, sink):
    root = etree.Element('root')
    for name, attr in d.items():
        etree.SubElement(root, 'element', attr)
    etree.ElementTree(root).write(sink, encoding='utf-8')

main()
```

Save this code to `merge-xml` file and run `chmod +x merge-xml`. Then:

```py
$ ./merge-xml base.xml new.xml >merge.xml
```

Here's Python 2.4+ compatible version:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from xml.dom import minidom

def main():
    output_file = getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout)
    dict2xml(merge_dicts(*map(xml2dict, sys.argv[1:])), output_file)

def xml2dict(source):
    doc = minidom.parse(source)
    return dict((el.getAttribute('name'), attr2dict(el.attributes))
                for el in doc.getElementsByTagName('element'))

def attr2dict(nodemap):
    d = {}
    for i in range(nodemap.length):
        attr = nodemap.item(i)
        d[attr.name] = attr.value
    return d

def merge_dicts(base, new):
    merged = {}
    # for each element from new xml
    for name, attr in new.items():
        # combine attributes from base and new xmls preferring new values
        d = merged[name] = base.get(name, {})
        d.update(attr)
    return merged

def dict2xml(d, sink):
    doc = minidom.getDOMImplementation().createDocument(None, "root", None)
    root = doc.documentElement
    for name, attr in d.items():
        el = doc.createElement('element')
        for name, value in attr.items():
            el.setAttribute(name, value)
        root.appendChild(el)
    sink.write(doc.toprettyxml(encoding='utf-8'))

main()
```

Comment: I tried with above python script, but  I get:

  File "./merge-xml", line 10
    for el in etree.parse(source).iter('element')}
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax



$ ls /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python*

Comment: use python2.7 to run the script

Comment: I could see 2.4 version of it & I tried : #!/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python2.4 in the first line of your script & still see same error. I need to wait till 2.7 gets installed if that version is mandate to run script in my working controlled environment

Comment: @user1587504: I've added Python 2.4 compatible solution